# 550, b'[SPF] The SPF record for domain prohibits this host from sending mail on\nbehalf of domain

Tags: python, email, flask, dns, smtplib

I have a simple Flask form where users send me messages. The code is below:

```
def send_general_query(email, message, name):        
    receiver_email = sender_email = Config.SMTP_SENDER
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Message'
    msg['From'] = email
    msg['To'] = receiver_email
    html = f"""
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>
        <p>From: {name}</p>            
        <p>{message}</p>
        </body>
        </html>
    """
    msgText = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(msgText)
    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP(Config.SMTP_SERVER, 587) as 
smtpObj:
            smtpObj.ehlo()
            smtpObj.starttls()
            smtpObj.login(Config.SMTP_SENDER, Config.SMTP_PASSWORD)
            smtpObj.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, 
msg.as_string())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

So it is basically sending the emails to myself. When I'm testing the form using some well known domains like **gmail** and **yahoo** I get no error and messages are delivered to my mailbox.
But when I use other custom email domains in the form I get SPF Failure below:

> (550, b'[SPF] The SPF record for custom_domain.com prohibits this host from
> sending mail on\nbehalf of custom_domain.com found in From: message header.')

I recon it is because my `sender_email = (Config.SMTP_SENDER)` does not match with `msg['From'] = email`

I tried to include SPF record to my DNS like this:

> "v=spf1 include:_spf.custom_domain.com ~all"

but the form stil returns the same error.
I can of course left this line empty `msg['From'] = ''` and return the user's email in the email body but then I need to manually copy/paste that email to the header when I want to reply the user using my mailbox.
Why the code does accept mismatches between `sender_email` and `msg['From']` with some domains and does not accept with others?

Comment: It's because the SPF policy for this domain says you are not allowed to do this. Either change the SPF to be more lenient (if you have the power to do that, and understand the consequences) or use a different domain which doesn't disallow this. Not a programming question.

Comment: For someone who is facing the same issue the solution might be to convert `email` variable to `str` and add extra empty space behind `&nbsp`. The final line for headers is `msg['From'] = str(email)+'&nbsp'`. This approach works in the above code, sending mail to any domains and replying to senders without issues.

Comment: The reason that works is that the `From:` address is no longer valid at all; the `&nbsp` could easily be replaced with any other string, as long as it doesn't match an existing domain with a strict SPF record any longer. You might want to wreck it with a less disturbing string (maybe replace ".com" with ".cοｍ"?) or, again, send from a domain which you are actually allowed to send from.

Comment: For some reason when I tried to replace it with just empty quotes like this `msg['From'] = str(email)+''` it didn't worked. At least it works now and I'm happy. Domain is fixed and I don't really want to change it. I haven't tried the question mark but other characters. The form delivers the message but I could simply hit **Reply** button and send the message back to the user beacuse there was invalid email address.

Comment: Because adding an empty string to the end of a string doesn't change it at all.